# Tree Layouts in JgraphX and JgraphT

Tags: data-visualization, graph-visualization, jgrapht

I am trying to build a visualization tool for Decision Trees (and several refinements in the algebraic decision diagram world, once that works) using JgraphT to support the underlying data structures, and JgraphX to throw the structure onto the screen.  (I'm new to both packages.)

I gather JgraphX has quite a history-- it seemed as though the Facade and TreeLayout classes from [Jgraph 5.13](http://touchflow.googlecode.com/hg-history/75fada644b2a19c744130923cbd34747fba861a2/doc/jgraphmanual.pdf) would be a step in the right direction, but I can't find anything similar in the more recent [JgraphX](http://jgraph.github.com/mxgraph/docs/manual_javavis.html) packages.  (If I understand the history, Jgraph was renamed to JgraphX sometime after the 5.13 version was released, and the version numbers started over-- is that correct?)  Nor can I find the legacy Jgraph 5.13 jar files anywhere.

Specific questions:

1. Does Jgraph 5.13 exist anywhere, and can someone point me to it?
2. Does JgraphX support the same tree layout features under a different name or paradigm?

Any help will be appreciated, otherwise I'm going to have to manhandle JgraphT/JgraphX until I have a tree layout tool from scratch, which does not fit my definition of "fun."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JGraphX was a completely rewrite from scratch, which is why we didn't call it JGraph 6 and the versioning started from 1.0.

JGraphX does have tree/hierarchical layouts in it.

Obviously, JGraphT is not a related project to us, so it's unfortunate they didn't update. There is a [post on our forum](http://forum.jgraph.com/questions/133/using-jgraphx-to-visualize-jgrapht) relating to this. I haven't tested the bridge, but the idea is right.

JGraphX does have its own analysis package too, btw. You might want to check whether that meets your needs and whether you need JGraphT at all.

We do provide downloads of the later version of JGraph 5 [here](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph5archive.html).

Comment: Thanks, David.  I hope I did not come across as overly critical; my intent was just to lay out the basic facts of the situation for others in the future, not to imply that various working groups are under the obligation to work together to make stuff for me for free...!

Answer (score 0):

My suspicions seem to be correct:  Jgraph changed significantly in its evolution to JgraphX, and JgraphT hasn't (or won't) catch up to it.  Exporting from JgraphT to a Jgraph format works much better if an older version of Jgraph (not more than 5.xx) is used-- then the facades, layout tools, etc, interface properly.

And an older version of Jgraph, version 5.13.00, is found [here.](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jgraph/jgraph/5.13.0.0)